# Choosing a USB hub

Tags: usb-power, usb-hub

I've read that using self-powered USB hubs with Raspberry Pi tends to be problematic. My first discovery today is that I will prevent some problem buying a USB-2 hub.

My second concern is to power on the Raspberry through the hub too. I am confused about the back power problems.

Should I avoid any hub that backpowers the Raspberry, and use the micro-usb power cable instead?

I was going to purchase the Amazon Basics USB3, but this exact model is reported to not work. I am looking at the USB2 one, but purchase options are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you find a hub that does provide back power, I wouldn't use it, as the RPi was not designed to be powered through the USB peripheral ports. On the other hand, there are hubs out there that can be powered by the host or by a wall adapter; I would recommend one of them. The RPi may not provide enough current through its USB ports to power all of your peripherals, and such a hub would take the guesswork out of it.

Secondly, there is no reason to spend extra money on a USB 3.x hub because no current RPi model supports USB 3.0, and if the host device doesn't support the protocol, you won't see any performance gains in your peripherals.

Answer (score 0):

I use a USB 3.0 hub to power my RPi3B+ cluster through the microUSB power connector. I use a **plugable** brand hub and it has a beefy power supply. It powers 5 RPi3B+ without an issue. The standard USB ports provide power -- you cannot use them to power the RPi.

That was sufficient reason for me to invest in one. ;-)